# gcc objdump - what is section .ARM.exidx.text

Tags: c++, gcc, binaryfiles

I need to find out what a particular BYTE - `.obj` address `0x584a7` - in my `.obj` is mapped to i.e. what is responsible for generating it (code/debug info/etc).

I've successfully run [`objdump -xSsDg`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) on my `.obj` file.

Looking at the output, I've identified the areas that refer to that byte:

**First section**: note the address is `0x584a0` and the size is `8` so this is what includes my byte of interest (`0x584a7`)

```
1012 .ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE 00000008  00000000  00000000  000584a0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

...

**Second section**: using a hex editor, I've identified that this data - `00000000 00000080` - matches my actual `.obj` file. The first four `0` at the start of the line indicate the offset INTO this section, which itself starts at `0x584a0`

```
Contents of section .ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE:
 0000 00000000 00000080                    ........
```

...

**Third section**: looks like code but not sure what is what.

```
Disassembly of section .ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE:

00000000 <.ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE>:
   0:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
            0: R_ARM_PREL31 .text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE
            0: R_ARM_NONE   __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1
   4:   80000000    andhi   r0, r0, r0
            4: R_ARM_PREL31 .ARM.extab.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE
```

So I have my `.cpp` and I have the `.obj` and I can see the mangled name has something to do with `QHash`, `QString`, `QHashData`  . . .

**QUESTION**

How do I conclusively map this section to a specific . . . THING be it code or debug info or . . . whatever so that I can know what affects this particular byte.

Answer (score 2):

In an ARM object file, sections named .ARM.exidx.text.* contain the exception index table. Each entry in this table contains the association between a function in the code being compiled and its exception-handling code; in other words, each entry specifies what should happen when an exception is thrown during execution of the function (or in other cases where the function call stack frame needs to be unwound outside the normal code execution path). These sections don't contain ARM or Thumb instructions, so their contents cannot be disassembled, and the `andeq` and `andhi` instructions you are seeing in your disassembly are misleading (the `-D` option you are passing to objdump makes it disassemble the contents of all object sections, even if they don't contain instructions).

In your case, you are looking at the frame unwinding instructions associated to the deleteNode() method of the QHash class from the Qt library. The format of these instructions is defined in the exception handling ABI for the ARM architecture (available for download at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0038b/IHI0038B_ehabi.pdf), and specifically at section 9.3 of the document.

Comment: The *sounds* right. I'll wait for at least one upvote before I accept.